# Docker automated builds with application in a separate repository

Tags: docker

I became a member of a GitHub organization for an application, and was working to enable automated builds on Docker Hub. The main application code is in a separate repository from the dockerfile, and other related files.

Ideally, I would like the image to be built when commits are pushed to the main application repository, using the dockerfile from the other repository so that everything is automated, without having to push changes to the dockerfile repo to build new images.

My question is if this is even possible. It doesn't appear to be, at least without setting up a really complicated workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hook starting your pipeline on changes to the main app repository. The pipeline would clone the code from the main app repo to work with its contents. It then  starts a script (e.g. bash) that clones the other repo (using git) to a temp folder, copies the needed files (like the dockerfile) from the other repo (in the temp folder) into the cloned main app repository, does the build magic and does with 'the image' whatever is needed (e.g. pushing it to a docker repo or such).
That is a process we have in our company for repositories that depend on each other.